# jquery access column of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of vectors as follows:

```
var mutliDimArr = [[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]];
```

I wish to form another array of the i'th column elements 
for example if i write a function getColumnarArray(1),
then it must return an new array [0,0,1] ..which are the 2nd elements each from the above mutliDimArr

I tried the following, but it is not giving me the desired results.:

```
function getColumnarArraycolumn(){
    var output = [];
    var column = 1;


    $.map(multiDimArray, function( arrayVect, column) {
        output.push(arrayVect[column]);
    });

    console.log(output);
}
```

Please advise,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in JavaScript array method - map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

So your code may look like:

```
var columnArr = mutliDimArr.map(function(row) {
    return row[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

passed 2nd parameter in `map` callback function, it's current object index,

```
var column = 1;
 $.map(multiDimArray, function( arrayVect, index) { 
       //arrayVect object index not global variable
        output.push(arrayVect[column]);
 });
```

```js
function getColumnarArraycolumn(multiDimArray) {
  var output = [];
  var column = 1;


  $.map(multiDimArray, function(arrayVect, index) {
    output.push(arrayVect[column]);
  });

  alert(JSON.stringify(output));
}
var mutliDimArr = [
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0]
];
getColumnarArraycolumn(mutliDimArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See here a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgzq9qgd/2/)

```
var multiDimArray = [[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]];
  var output = [];
    var column = 1;

    $.map(multiDimArray, function( arrayVect) {
        output.push(arrayVect[column]);
    });

    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this you will get the answer ,

```
var column = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < mutliDimArr.length; i++) {
console.log(mutliDimArr[i][column]);
}
```